# Bind tab to observablecollection in model in xaml

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a question concerning data binding with tabs.
I have the following xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="SuperAtomsController.GUI.windowAnalog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"          
    Title="windowAnalog" Height="900" Width="1400"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">

    <Grid>
        <TabControl Height="459" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="188,278,0,0" Name="tabControl1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=model.sequences}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="883">

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class windowAnalog : Window
{
    public Data model;                           
    public windowAnalog(Data model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        InitializeComponent();                             
    }
}
```

But with this nothing appears in the tabcontrol (model.sequences is of the type `ObservableCollection<>`). If remove the itemssource in xaml and add the following in the c# code `tabControl1.ItemsSource = model.sequences;` after the `InitializeComponent();` it works fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly your binding isn't resolving, check your debug output window for helpful diagnostic messages.

I can't recall but I think model may need to be a property instead of a field for WPF property path to work. Otherwise maybe it was a problem with the DataContext. You coudl try doing this.DataContext = this to your constructor before InitializeComponent() instead of your DataContext xaml.